# How to limit table width to non-breaking td-width

Tags: html, html-table, tablelayout

"UPDATE":

**Error on my end.** Discovered a CSS error, that made all tables aim for 100%. 
Sorry that I bothered you.

---

I have a question regarding the default behaviour of tables.

I need to have a table where the width is only as much as the width supplied by the length of the longest table-row.

For example:

```
<!-- Table width should be cellpadding+cellspacing+aaa+bbb-->
<table>
    <tr> 
       <td>aaa</td>
       <td>bbb</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<!-- Table width should be cellpadding+cellspacing+dddddddddddddd+bbb-->
<table>
    <tr> 
       <td>ddddddddddddddddddd</td>
       <td>bbb</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have only been able to build tables which have a fixed width or use the width of the container-element. I want them to only use as much space as the `<td>` demand.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are trying to acchived. Don't the tables only take as much space as needed already? https://jsfiddle.net/91dnesxn/

Comment: If you mean, for instance, that you expect these tables to display side by side if they are narrow enough, please edit the question and say so.

Comment: Thanks you for your help everyone. I discovered an error inside an imported css file which rendered all tables on 100% width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with following css

```
table tr td {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-word;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```